# named connection not found (Entity framework problem)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm building multi-project Application where some UserControl, the user control has a Entitymodel object (`myDBContainer db = new myDBContainer()`), when i drop my user control on my a form i got the following designer error

> The specified connectionis either not
>   found in the configuration, not
>   intended to be used with the
>   entityclient provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution for this but, I don't know is it the optimum or not. I put the connection string in the app.config through Settings file, and change the named connection in the constructor for the EF model designer to read this connection as the following

```
public InvDB() : base(Properties.Settings.Default.InvDB, "InvDB")
```

but this solution, you've to make this change every time you open the EF designer, but it's good for now.

Comment: So you have the wrong connection name on your model. Like I said in my answer, the connection string isn't there. Fix the model or the .config file to agree.

Comment: No, the connection already exists and named correctly and every time I open the Model it reset it again so the problem is not in the connection name, you got me?. I thing this maybe an "Beta" issue.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the *Entity Framework* connection string isn't found in the Web.config or App.config for your project. Note that this connection string is not the same as the DB connection string.

Comment: No it is there and it is as the EF write it, i didn't change it

Comment: You are telling me it's there, but the EF says it isn't. No offense, but I would tend to believe the EF. Are you sure you're looking at the *right* config file? If your model and main app are in different assemblies, the correct config file at runtime will be the main app's file, not the model's, and hence *not* the config file the EF wrote.